# Can I tell if a user has accepted my activity's request for screen pinning?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I was reading the overview for the new Android 5.0 Lollipop API (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html), and I became interested in the Screen Pinning feature.

I can successfully request that Screen Pinning be started by my Activity, but I have no idea if the user accepts the pinning request or not. The startLockTask() method has no return value, and I didn't see any mention of a callback.

I would like my activity to react differently depending on whether or not the screen has been successfully pinned. Is this possible or are my hopes a bit too high?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually just found the answer to this question.

The method is in ActivityManager, not Activity, and no references are made from the Activity API, so I didn't see it right away.

You can find out if your activity has entered task locking mode (or Screen Pinning) via this code:

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 if (activityManager.isInLockTaskMode())
 {
     // react accordingly
 }
```

Comment: ```isInLockTaskMode``` is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isInLockTaskMode%28%29

Preferred method seems to be ```getLockTaskModeState```: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLockTaskModeState()

Comment: Good answer, but the main idea is avoid pooling to detect if the user accepted the pinning mode. That callback would be useful from Android SDK @AndroidDEV